# what is the reason behind using these lines in CSS

Tags: css, web

why people use this in their **CSS code** what is the reason behind it? what is the advantage of this?

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -o-flex;
```

Comment: Backwards compatibility, to enable flexbox in older browsers, that did implement it behind a _vendor prefix_ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backwards compatibility: CSS3 is completely backwards compatible with earlier CSS versions. That old site running on a previous CSS version can be reworked with CSS3.
Also, with browsers already compatible to CSS2 and other versions, changes with CSS3 are reflected perfectly as well. And if you just want to add to it and not rework the entire site, that’s ok, it’s all possible!

PS: Keep in mind though, you won’t be getting the added speed benefits everywhere if only a part of your site is built with CSS3.